# Are $\lim_{x \to y}$ and $\lim_{y \to x}$ the same thing?

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

I have an expression $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(a+h)^2\sin(a+h)-a^2\sin(a)}{h}$$

I tried to substitute $$a+h=k$$

So to change the limit, I could write $$\lim_{a\to k}$$ or $$\lim_{k\to a}$$

My question is, are they any different?

Comment: You don't have an *equation*. The equals sign in your first expression makes no sense.

Comment: Oh yes my bad, edited it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an expression $\lim_{h\to 0} F(a,h)$, the variable $a$ is not bound while the variable $h$ is. That is, the resulting expression is a function of $a$:
$$
G(a) = \lim_{h\to 0} F(a,h).
$$

Hence, this can't be written as $\lim_{a\to k} …$, since that would make $a$ a bound variable.

So the substitution $a+h=k$ makes $k$ the new bound variable, keeping $a$ unbound:
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} F(a,h) = \lim_{k\to a} F(a,k-a).
$$

---

Here's an example regarding the more general question in the title:
$$
\lim_{x\to y} xy = y^2 \neq x^2 = \lim_{y\to x} xy.
$$
One is a function of $y$, the other is a function of $x$.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. But is there a better way to solve this equation?

Comment: It's the derivative $f'(a)$ for $f(x)=x^2\sin(x)$. Use the product rule and $\sin'=\cos$ to compute it.